# Progress bar color not consistent in Lollipop

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I used the following code to create a progress bar. I tried to change its color, it works for Android 6.0+, but it does not work while I run it on my Android 5.1 emulator.

How can I solve this problem?

```
    <ProgressBar
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/progressb"
         style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
         android:progressTint="@color/colorAccent"
         android:progressTintMode="multiply"
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think to support the backward Android OS phones, I did it programmatically. I used to add below code to handle

```
Drawable drawable = progressBar.getProgressDrawable();
int colorAccent = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, colorAccent);
} else {
    drawable.mutate().setColorFilter(colorAccent, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
}
```